Login As Customer doesn't reflect cart items at actual customer login
We have a clean Magento build with version 2.4.5-p1. We are facing issues with "Login As Customer" core Magento extension. We successfully logged in to customer's account using "Login As Customer" feature at backend. Then added products to cart.
However, when we browse frontend store in another browser and logs in with same customer with username/password, we don't see any product to cart on homepage/my account pages etc. until we browse cart page. Even minicart doesn't show any product. But when we navigate to cart page, it starts showing the cart items (on minicart as well as on cart page) which are added from "Login As Customer" session.
Can someone help me to resolve this?
Thanks in advance!

Could you please check your logs or any other modules that might be affecting the cart? By default, the value was displayed in the minicart upon login. It seems like one of your modules or a cache setting is impacting this behavior.

@GrazittiDev I tried disabling cache but didn't work. If I login in another browser after adding product to cart from "Login As Customer" session then I can see products in cart. The issue is happening when I already logged in from other browser. Not sure which other module is causing the issue here.

@GrazittiDev I also tried setting cacheable="false" to minicart block but no luck.

I believe when you were already logged IN, then cart session is already there which will update when move on the cart page or add any item to cart.

Yes, but when we reload the page it should show the cart items those are added from "Login As Customer" session. Do you agree?
